# What is 5th Jaw?

Tags: meter

I just purchased this meter box and need to make sure it will work fine as a standard 240 volt residential meter. I noticed it says `5th Jaw` in the title. What is this and is it anything I need to be concerned about? Thanks

[Siemens MM0202S1200RHJ MM0202S1200RHJ meter main, 200 Amp, solar input provision, ringless cover, 5th jaw](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00NT5SU8M)

Comment: Have you web searched on "what is 5th jaw meter"?  [This page](https://www.electriciantalk.com/threads/5th-terminal.25074/) seems to explain it - to allow phase-ground voltage service through a single-phase meter fed from a 3-phase supply.

Comment: @relayman357 yes I have, and others. I went here to get expert feedback. I saw several different explanations for it, including lower voltage usage.

Comment: Can you ask your local electrical distributor about this specific base?  They will have to approve it anyway before you connect (if new service).